# how to return the selected text parent element html

Tags: javascript, html

im trying to do something with android, edit a html in a webview, sending js commands to the page, i have this code working

```
function changeColor()  {
    var selection;

    //Get the selected stuff
    if(window.getSelection)
        selection = window.getSelection();
    else if(typeof document.selection!="undefined")
        selection = document.selection;

    //Get a the selected content, in a range object
    var range = selection.getRangeAt(0);

    //If the range spans some text, and inside a tag, set its css class.
    if(range && !selection.isCollapsed){
        if(selection.anchorNode.parentNode == selection.focusNode.parentNode)
        alert(selection.anchorNode){
            var span = document.createElement('span');
            span.style.color = 'red';
            range.surroundContents(span);
        }
    }
}
```

The doubts are:

1) How can i add more than one style if it already have other? eg; background, bold and italic, not necessary in the same time

2) and how can i get the html of the selected paragraph, the html is like this:

```
 <p class="paragrafo" style="text-indent: 40px" align="justify" id="p4"> **<span style="color:black">Text Hereeee.</span>
    <div id="c4" class="comment"></div>**</p>
```

i need the html code inside the

above, so after i can restore it later

Answer (score 1):

Partially solved:

Solution of number 1:

i dont know =(

Solution of number 2:

```
function highlightSelection()  {
  var selection;
  //Get the selected stuff
  if(window.getSelection)
    selection = window.getSelection();
  else if(typeof document.selection!="undefined")
    selection = document.selection;
  //Get a the selected content, in a range object
  var range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
  //If the range spans some text, and inside a tag, set its css class.
  if(range && !selection.isCollapsed)
  {
    if(selection.anchorNode.parentNode == selection.focusNode.parentNode)
    {
      var span = document.createElement('span');
span.style.color = 'red';
      range.surroundContents(span);
      var x = window.getSelection()
      var z = x.anchorNode.parentNode

      //o que vai ta dentro do p em html
       var html = z.parentNode.innerHTML; //here the content
      var id = z.parentNode.id; //here show the id of the element



    }
  }
}
```